# How to write Cross Join with Group By in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table which might contain duplicate records therefore as a first step, I need to group the duplicate records and assign common number for duplicate records. After grouping, I need to insert those records into another temp table as given below.

For Ex:

[image]

And I am expecting a cross join select query which results like below:

[image]

Source Table:

```
ID  Name    Amount
1   ABC     200
2   DEF     100
3   ABC     200
4   GHI     700
5   ABC     200
```

And my select query should return a resultset like below.

```
ID  MatchingID  CommonID
1    3           X123X
1    5           X123X
3    1           X123X
3    5           X123X
5    1           X123X
5    3           X123X
```

If record 1 is matching with 3 and 5 then, my select query should contain below records. And for all the records CommonID should be same.

1 as a primary and 3 as a secondary

1 as a primary and 5 as a secondary

3 as a primary and 1 as a secondary

3 as a primary and 5 as a secondary

5 as a primary and 1 as a secondary

5 as a primary and 3 as a secondary

Below query gives me a result but I am expecting a result which should ignore where PrimaryID and SecondaryID are same.

```
SELECT A.ID AS PrimaryID, B.ID AS SecondaryID, 
          A.Name + CAST(A.Amount AS VARCHAR(10)) as CommonID
   FROM TEMPOC AS A
   CROSS JOIN TEMPOC AS B 
   WHERE A.Amount = B.Amount AND A.Name = B.NAme

PrimaryID   SecondaryID CommonID
1   1   ABC100
1   3   ABC100
1   5   ABC100
2   2   DEF200
3   1   ABC100
3   3   ABC100
3   5   ABC100
4   4   GHI400
5   1   ABC100
5   3   ABC100
5   5   ABC100
```

But If I use ON condition, I am getting below error.

[image]

Comment: Why have you tagged *both* SQL Server 2012 and 2008? Which are you *actually* using? **Both** are also *completely* unsupported (the latter for well over 3 years), so you really need to get your upgrade path sorted.

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` in your derived tables anyway? You have no aggregation.

Comment: @Larnu - I am using SQL Server 2019 version but it was not listed there so I tagged 2012 & 2008.

Comment: @Larnu - I need to generate CommonID for duplicate records hence I used Group By.

Comment: @Larnu - Please ignore the query which my be wrong. If possible suggest me better approach for the expected result.

Comment: *"I am using SQL Server 2019 version but it was not listed there so I tagged 2012 & 2008."* Check again: [[tag:sql-server-2019]] That doesn't explain  why you tagged 2008 *and* 2012 either. 2 wrongs don't might a right.

Comment: *"I need to generate CommonID for duplicate records hence I used Group By."* This doesn't explain anything either. The `GROUP BY` clause is for when you are aggregating. There is *no* aggregation in your query.

Comment: I would suggest that you provide some **consumable** sample data and expected results here; what you are asking isn't clear.

Comment: I think what is missing here is that the NAME column is what is duplicate, correct?  is there any other criteria for a duplicate record?

Comment: @Hogan - Name & Amount are duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a cross join to find all combinations based on name and amount as the shared record you would do this,

```
   SELECT A.ID AS PrimaryID, B.ID AS SecondaryID, 
          A.Name + CAST(A.Amount AS VARCHAR(10)) as CommonID
   FROM Table1 AS A
   JOIN Table1 AS B ON A.Name = B.Name AND A.Amount = B.Amount
                   AND A.ID != B.ID
```

As you can see, it is much "simpler" than what you were doing, since what you want is the result of a CROSS JOIN the code is not complex.

Comment: I want a commonID to be generated based on Group By.. Here Group By columns are Name & Amount..

Comment: @TechLearner -- that is what I did.  You don't need a GROUP BY.  Please run this code to see.

Comment: `A.Name + CAST(A.Amount AS VARCHAR(10))` is a generated id based on name and amount

Comment: I executed this query and I am getting error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.'

Comment: @TechLearner -- sounds like you made a typo -- please show me the exact text you ran

Comment: I have updated the question with your answer. Please check it once.

Comment: YOU CHANGED ON WITH WHERE @TechLearner

Comment: Yes, with ON I am getting error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.'

Comment: @TechLearner Dude you have this : `CROSS JOIN TEMPOC AS B WHERE A.Amount = B.Amount AND A.Name = B.NAme` it should be this `CROSS JOIN TEMPOC AS B  ON A.Amount = B.Amount AND A.Name = B.NAme`  You have the word WHERE in your code and it should be the word ON

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the question with ON condition. Please suggest me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: @TechLearner -- I'm sorry it looks like the "CROSS JOIN" keyword works differently on SQL Server than on DB2 (where I used it last).  Please try just using JOIN for this with an additional check on IDs I added above.